# Is it a good idea to have a LAMP on your desktop

Tags: security, lamp, webserver

I am a web-developer. I have a LAMP installed on my daily driver desktop ubuntu system. It is not accessible from the outside because I haven't forwarded any ports to it. However a friend told me that it is a bad idea to have LAMP on your machine. Is it really a bad/good idea to have a LAMP on your local machine? (Apache and MySQL are disabled from the autostart menu - I start them manually when I need them with `systemctl`).

Comment: And where should you keep them? If there are for development then you need them there!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not a bad idea. The only downside is that LAMP consumes resource.  But it harms little as long as you can afford it.

Also, many applications (for example, express framework) nowadays run nodejs webservers of their own, so how bad could it be to run another apache?